# What science or psychology is behind the Landmark Forum's coursework?

Tags: reference-request, positive-psychology

[The Landmark Forum](http://www.landmarkeducation.com/) is a self-help seminar focusing on helping individuals to make positive changes in their lives by chaing their point of view and using logic to break down emotions to change the way one feels.

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landmark_Education#History), the Landmark Forum is based on [est, the Erhard Seminars Training](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erhard_Seminars_Training), which itself is based on the [Socratic Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method). However, is there any science or actual psychology behind the Landmark Forum?

Comment: no trained professionals, just a bunch of volunteers, doing what????? brainwashing NLP, by uneducated volunteers... forcing there salvation on any and everyone who will join. sounds a lot like jehova witness to me......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer to your question .

I got the sense that Landmark was in the same category as other so called 'power' therapies such as neurolinguistuc programming etc. The 7:30 report - a *credible* Australian current affairs program - did an story on Landmark last year.

**References**

http://www.abc.net.au/7.30/content/2011/s3367386.htm

Devilly, Grant J. (2005) "Power Therapies and possible threats to the science of psychology and psychiatry", Australian and New Zealand Journal of Psychiatry, Vol. 39, No. 6, June 2005, pp. 437-445(9)

Comment: This quote pretty much sums it up for me: "What we do is personal and professional growth training and development. It's not therapy, it's not psychology, it's not psychological in nature"